# RewriteRule in folder breaks parent (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
# /.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule "^([^/]+)/root/(.*)"   "$1/index.php?root=$2"

# /folder/.htaccess
RewriteRule "^sub/(.*)"            "index.php?sub=$1"
```

Each folder's `RewriteRule` works in isolation:

- `/folder/root/hi   => /folder/index.php?root=hi`
- `/folder/sub/hello => /folder/index.php?sub=hello`

**Q:** Why does adding *any* `RewriteRule` in the subfolder (`/folder/.htacces`) break the one in the web root (causes 404)? What do I need to do to create rules on different levels?

I've tried adding `RewriteOptions Inherit(Down)`, but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: The first URL causes 404

Comment: Indeed, my bad. I had already spotted and corrected that error. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I've tried `RewriteOptions InheritDown` in the root, `RewriteOptions Inherit` in the folder, and both at the same time. Nothing made any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `RewriteEngine On` in the `/folder/.htaccess` then the mod_rewrite directives in the parent config will be completely overridden, since mod_rewrite directives don't inherit by default.

However, even if you enable mod_rewrite inheritance, the directives still won't work, because mod_rewrite *inheritance* "virtually copies" the directives "in-place", as if the directives are in the same config file - in the same scope (with the same *directory-prefix*).

So, with `RewriteOptions Inherit` in the `/folder/.htaccess` file, the directives are effectively processed like this:

```
# /folder/.htaccess
RewriteRule "^sub/(.*)"            "index.php?sub=$1"

# Inherited from parent config
RewriteRule "^([^/]+)/root/(.*)"   "$1/index.php?root=$2"
```

The pattern `"^([^/]+)/root/(.*)"` simply won't match if used in the scope of the `/folder/.htaccess` file - which is what's happening when using mod_rewrite inheritance.

IF the `/.htaccess` (root) directives are *always* inherited then you could modify the root directive to read something like the following (removing the parent directory from the rule):

```
RewriteRule ^root/(.*) index.php?root=$1 [L]
```

(Yes, it matches the directive already in the `/folder/.htaccess` file.)

However, the "problem" now is that directive probably won't work if *not* inherited as in your example. IF you specifically need it to work in both scenarios: when inherited from a subdirectory `.htaccess` file and directly from the document-root, then modify the directive to make the parent folder optional. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)?root/(.*) $1index.php?root=$3 [L]
```

You may still need to fix the `RewriteBase` directive, or remove it altogether.

mod_rewrite inheritance is not as *useful* as it at first appears. Directives - that are expected to be inherited - generally need to be specifically written to allow for this.

Comment: I guess the most robust approach is to add `RewriteRule`s in the deepest path. In my example, that means that both rewrites should be defined in `folder/.htaccess`. Would you agree?

Comment: That would possibly be the safest approach (or use only the `.htaccess` file in the document root). Using mod_rewrite inheritance (and multiple `.htaccess` files) does increase the complexity, making it harder to maintain and more chance to introduce bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your root .htaccess rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)?root/(.*)$ $1index.php?root=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This is to make initial part `[^/]+/` an *optional match* in order to make same rule work from root .htaccess as well as from a `/folder/.htaccess`.

Then have this in your `folder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)$ index.php?sub=$1 [L,QSA]
```

[`RewriteOptions Inherit`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) will inherit all rules and directives from parent .htaccess and will apply them in child's context *after* applying all the rules defined in child .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache 2.4, I've success by adding `RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore` in the parent `.htaccess`.